# Continuity in a topological group

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

The group of the real numbers under addition is a topological group ($\mathbb{R}$,$+$) with the usual topology. However, I can't see why the group operation (addition) is a continuous function. 
Would you like to show me why? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because for all $(x,y)\in\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ and for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a neighbourhood $V\ni(x,y)$ in $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ such that $\lvert z+w-(x+y)\rvert<\varepsilon$ for all $(z,w)\in V$. Namely, $V=\left]x-\frac\varepsilon2,x+\frac\varepsilon2\right[\times \left]y-\frac\varepsilon2,y+\frac\varepsilon2\right[$ works.

Answer (score 1):

In elementary analysis you should have learnt that $$a_n \to a, b_n \to b \implies a_n + b_n \to a+b.$$ This is exactly what you‘re citing.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather easy to check with the triangle inequality that

$$ \left| |(x+y)| - |(x'+y')| \right| \le |x-x'| + |y-y'|$$ for all $x,y,x',y' \in \Bbb R$ which implies what you say.